# MySQL: Combine data from rows in a table based on condition between two columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have a bed table in hospital like this in MySql

```
patient_id      date_started     date_stopped

1               2018-01-10       2018-01-15
1               2018-01-15       2018-01-28
1               2018-01-28       2018-02-05
2               2018-01-15       2018-02-10
2               2018-03-05       2018-04-12
3               2018-01-10       2018-01-20
3               2018-01-20       null
4               2018-02-10       2018-02-10
```

Now I don't want those rows whose date_stopped for a patient is same as date_started of a different row. I want the output to be like

```
patient_id     date_started     date_stopped

1              2018-01-10       2018-02-05
2              2018-01-15       2018-02-10
2              2018-03-05       2018-04-12
4              2018-02-10       2018-02-10
```

If I do INNER JOIN, I am getting multiple rows

```
SELECT
  *
FROM bed AS bed_1
INNER JOIN bed_2
  ON bed_2.patient_id = bed_1.patient_id
  AND bed_2.date_started != bed_2.date_stopped
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a primary key for this table?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Yes. we have a primary key

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by writing a procedure that accepts
patient_id and date_stopped and recurses until the date_stopped is not equal to the next date_started for the same patient

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FINAL_STOP_DATE(IN patientId INT,IN dateStopped DATETIME, OUT finalStopDate DATETIME)
 +  BEGIN
 +    DECLARE current_patient INT;
 +    DECLARE curr_start_date DATETIME;
 +    DECLARE curr_stop_date DATETIME;
 +    SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 250;
 +    SELECT patient_id,
 +      date_started,date_stopped
 +    INTO current_patient,curr_start_date,curr_stop_date
 +    FROM bed
 +          WHERE patient_id = patientId AND date_started = dateStopped
 +    LIMIT 1;
 +    if current_patient = patientId  AND curr_start_date = dateStopped THEN
 +      CALL FINAL_STOP_DATE(current_patient, curr_stop_date, finalStopDate);
 +    ELSE
 +      SET finalStopDate = dateStopped;
 +    END IF ;
 +  END;
```

So this procedure's output is the final stop date for given patient excluding all the consecutives start and stop dates midway

We can call this procedure for every record in bed table and select the output of this procedure as date_ended column. To achieve this we need to write one mediator function because we can't call a procedure from select clause in SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_FINAL_STOP_DATE(patientId INT, date_stopped DATETIME)
 +  RETURNS DATETIME
 +  BEGIN
 +    DECLARE final_stop_date DATETIME;
 +    CALL FINAL_STOP_DATE(patientId, date_stopped, final_stop_date);
 +    RETURN final_stop_date;
 +  END;
```

Now call this function from select clause which will select the return value as date_ended column Now do GROUP BY patient_id, date_ended on the result set and select the MIN date_started

```
SELECT patient_id, 
       MIN(date_started),
       GET_FINAL_STOP_DATE(patient_id,date_stopped) AS date_ended
FROM bed
GROUP BY patient_id, date_ended
```

And the final result will be like

```
patient_id     date_started     date_ended

1              2018-01-10       2018-02-05
2              2018-01-15       2018-02-10
2              2018-03-05       2018-04-12
3              2018-01-10       null
4              2018-02-10       2018-02-10
```

At last, add a where condition saying date_ended should not be null to get the expected result